# how to fix "expected [ Array(9) ] to deeply equal [ Array(11) ]" error

Tags: javascript

Given two numbers X and Y, write a function that:
returns even numbers between X and Y, if X is greater than Y else it returns odd numbers between x and y

expected result:

```
12, 0 => [2,4,6,8,10]
```

actual result:

```
12, 0 => [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ]
0, 12 => [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 ]
```

```js
const number_game = (x, y) => {
  let numArray = [];

  if (x === 0 && y === 0) {
    return [];
  } else if (x > y) {
    for (let i = y + 1; i < x; i++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        numArray.push(i);
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (let i = x + 1; i < y; i++) {
      if (i % 2 == 1) {
        numArray.push(i);
      }
    }
  }

  return numArray;
}

console.log(number_game(12, 0));
console.log(number_game(0, 12));
```

Comment: It's showing the desired results in the snippet

Comment: Please provide some information on the problem? As I cannot see anything wrong with this